# Phaser js and Apache Cordova green rectangle error

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, phaser-framework

I have an apk that works and the normal file and although I emulate ios for Cordova there is an error where images won't show up and green rectangles are the only things displayed for some reason.

```js
preload() {
    this.load.image('space', './imgs/spacegif.jpg');
    this.load.image('rocket', './imgs/rocket.png');
    this.load.image('alien', './imgs/alien.gif');
    this.load.image('asteroid', './imgs/asteroid.png');
    this.load.image('cargo', './imgs/cargo.png');
    this.load.image('hatchPanels', './imgs/hatchPanel.png');
    this.load.image('bullets', './imgs/laserBlasts.jpg');
    this.load.image('primus', './imgs/primus.png');
    this.load.image('hatchIcon', './imgs/hatchIcon.png');
    // ...
}
```

There is the part where images are preloaded, and I even tried adding assets to Xcode and have them show up through that path. What should I do?

Comment: Welcome to SO. The green rectangles mean that the images can't be found. To be clear, when you test this on Android the images are loading, but they're not loading on iOS?

Comment: yes @JamesSkemp

Comment: Can you please show me what the image path would look like :)